# request.POST.get('encResp') returns None on PROD env (linux, Apache, MySQL, Python, Django), while the same work on local

Tags: python, django, apache, callback, payment-gateway

request.POST.get('encResp') returns None on PROD env (linux, Apache, MySQL, Python, Django),
 
while the same statement returns data as expected on my local env (Window 8, MySql, Python, Django)

Usecase Breif:
Payment Gateway (PG) Integration: Testing Phase: Code checked into PROD, with PG test urls still.
I submit to Payment URL ... that returns Response Data to my callback URL.
Control reaching to my callback url, but the said request.POST.get('encResp') is returning 'None'

NOTE: I am sending some data long with call url as query params .. and those are successfully received via the request.GET.get('qs')

call back url: (local works)
http://localhost:8000/payment/done/?qs=5b69961d5c3c1d06fc21c324804d8bb0f229798f20ebc4f89bc9b13bc5618cb3

call back url: (prod fails)
https://xxxxxxxxx.org.in/payment/done/?qs=df86a2638205e3b8989336da02cedf33

Not sure whats missing on PROD ... only difference i see is Apache2 webserver in between the call back which i dont have in local env

Appreciate some pointers/suggestions

Comment: We'd have to see your urls, views, django settings and apache settings to explore all the possible causes for this issue

Comment: Observation:\n
To the same Payment URL, <br>
when I submit from my WIndows Local env ... the response sent to callback function is of type POST ..  reuqest.method == POST<br><br>

But when I submit from my Linux Prod env ... the response sent to callback function is of type GET ... request.method == GET<br><br>

in both case request.GET.get('encResp') is None and request.POST.get('encResp') is None<br><br>

The bank tech supports says they are sending the response alright ... and i am receiving the same as POST.get('encResp') on my local dev env ... it is on PROD that it fails

Comment: Please edit your post instead. Comments don't support much formatting and quickly become unreadable.

Comment: This being said: " when I submit from my Linux Prod env ... the response sent to callback function is of type GET" (well this is a request, not a response but anyway) => something is redirecting the POST request, which make it loose all it's content (which is correct according to HTTP specs). This can be an issue with [your `settings.APPEND_SLASH̀`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#append-slash) and/or your apache settings (rewrite rules for example).

Comment: Kindly excuse my ignorance... this is my first question to stackoverflow .. i tried but would not find the option to edit my Initial question ... where i can add my urls,settings files ... please assist

Comment: No offense ;-) - and there _should_ be an "edit" link under your question's text - if not, check the FAQ or ask a moderator... (SO "privileges" rules can sometimes be a bit debatable but I have a hard time thinking a newcomer couldn't edit his own questions...)

Comment: Dear Bruno, (if I may call you by that) ... Really APPRECIATE the concern and effort the community at StackOverflow puts-in to help the developer world ... .... ......I have been a regular seeker of guidance/tips from this platform.. ...May be I can take motivation from this community and Contribute in any way possible going forward .. ... ... .... ... ..... ..... ..... ...... ..... ..... .... ... .. . . . . . . .. .. . . .... . .. . . . .. . . .

Comment: My Issue was indeed due to the Apache server settings that were redirectly all urls to the SSL layer... https ... ... .. .. is the process my callback url which i had mentioned as http .. ... would get redirected as well and loose its POST data ... .... .... ... .. Changing my call back url to https on PROD fixed the issue ... .... thanks